# M or m always appears before quotation marks "

Tags: macos

I have a MacBook air 2013 running Big Sur. As of yesterday anytime I press `"` `M"` appears. Any time I press `'` `m'` appears. I then have to go back and delete the m/M using back space.

Does anyone know what's happening?

Comment: Has that been added as a text replacement ? See keyboard in Sys settings or in the app?

Comment: Just checked on mine ( MacBook Pro 2016) updated last night and it does not do that.

Comment: Try an external keyboard.  Sounds like the internal one may be damaged.

Comment: It doesnm't happen with the external keyboard. Presume that means itm's the internal keyboard thats faulty and not a setting?

Comment: We gave you suggestions based on the information in your question. As you later qualified the test with a keyboard then you might be correct.